# joint_state_controller problem loading

Tags: ros, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem when go loading the joint_state_controller.

roslaunch joint_state_controller joint_state_controller.launch

process[joint_state_controller_spawner-1]: started with pid [17618]

[INFO] [WallTime: 1380940721.793944] [0.000000] Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller

[WARN] [WallTime: 1380940752.010181] [8.979000] Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/87466/joint_state_controller-problem-loading./) by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5418/eduardomaciel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that you don't have a running controller manager, or you are not launching the spawned script in the same namespace as the controller manager. Is this the case?

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2013-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5418/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-10-05**:
Hi Adolfo, thanks for reply.

Look these links, are when I start my project:

http://postimg.org/image/nhhetml8f/

http://postimg.org/image/6qez0wd5z/

http://postimg.org/image/o91zcz5rx/

The "joint_state_controller" is in the folder "ros_controller", not I created the code in my project folder. I start it there the "joint_state_controller".

Do you give me any tips how to do this?

Best regards.

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5418/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-10-05**:
Not start the controller using: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6844189

But...,

With my launch: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6844154

I start the controller using: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6844201

....and joint_state_controller run.

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5418/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-10-09**:
I managed to fix my problem.

**Comment by [Hououin Kyouma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1579/hououin-kyouma/) on 2013-11-07**:
Hi EduardoMaciel, could you tell me how you fixed this problem? I'm facing the same issue, would be great if you explained what the problem is. Thanks.

**Comment by [filipposanfilippo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21802/filipposanfilippo/) on 2016-04-20**:
Same problem on Jade. How did you fix this?